# update column values with the other column values using inner join in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

While implementing the below code, I got error message, "relation "n" does not exist"

```
UPDATE n
    SET n.var_a = a.var_b
    FROM table_n n INNER JOIN
         table_a a
         ON n.var_c = a.var_d AND lower(n.var_e) = lower(a.var_f);
```

However, the below code is working. What part should be corrected in the above code? I also tried with using full table names.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_n n INNER JOIN
     table_a a
     ON n.var_c = a.var_d AND lower(n.var_e) = lower(a.var_f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close.  This is the correct syntax for Postgres:

```
UPDATE table_n n
    SET var_a = a.var_b
    FROM table_a a 
    WHERE n.var_c = a.var_d AND lower(n.var_e) = lower(a.var_f);
```

In Postgres, you need to specify the table being updated in the `UPDATE` clause.  You can give it an alias, but aliases from the `FROM` clause are not recognized (hence your error).

Comment: Thank you. Work like a charm.